# What are trained models in NLP

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, opennlp

I am new to machine learning and NLP. Can anyone tell me what are training models with an examples? While coding in java using apache openNLP package, we always have to include some trained models (found here http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/ ) . What are they and how are they got?Are they some standarized models on a specific dataset like movie reviews , product reviews etc. I am really confused regarding this training phase of machine learning

Comment: Have you tried wikipedia? I just googled `trained model` and the first hit was: `Mathematical Model`, with a `jump to` link to the `Training` section.

Comment: @cel I want to know trained model specific to machine learning. I have read that we have to give certain data set as input to train a model for a machine then we can use it for analysis. I want to understand clearly. Its very vague in my mind. Explantions with examples may help.

Comment: `model` is not a term specific to machine learning. It is used in all fields of applied mathematics. In machine learning you often encounter `statistical mathematical models`. There's also a wiki page you can consult.

Comment: @cel oh I want to understand how do we work to build a trained model for some data set to make it useful at testing phase with example

Comment: Well, you don't build a trained model - you choose a model and then train it. Choosing the model is often not straight forward and requires a high level understaning how the data was generated. Don't expect a simple example here. There is none.

Comment: @cel So what do you suggest me, what approach should i chose to understand the training phase in general if there are no examples?

Comment: Well, if you are familiar with maths, grab a statistics textbook. Books that cover `bayesian data analysis` or `bayesian inference` will probably introduce the basic concepts needed to understand what's going on in machine learning. There are also good books on the statistical background of machine learning that could fit your needs.